# Why is my question getting downvotes, an unclear vote but no explanations? How can I improve this question?

Tags: discussion, closing, down-votes

The question: [Show the equivalence of these definitions of independence of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511226/show-the-equivalence-of-these-definitions-of-independence-of-random-variables)

Two books give two different definitions of independence of random variables, and I am trying to show that they are equivalent.

I don't see what the problems is/are.

Comment: I reformatted your post. For one, your question was entirely in the title, and there was no question in the body -- this is not a good idea in general. Your list was also not formatted very well. It looks like very small things, but it's sometimes enough to lead people to the downvote button: something that looks like a bunch of formulas jumbled together is not very well received in general.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi 1 Thanks for reformat. 2 Was it entirely in title? 'Why are these two definitions equivalent?'

Comment: ...I added that sentence myself... It was not in your original question.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Going to edit more then following you. Thanks

Comment: @NajibIdrissi HAHAHAHAHAHAHA dumb of me. Thanks a million!

Comment: In general people won't read your whole question at a first glance. They will scan it, look for keywords, and probably above all a question mark. If the question mark appears at the end after a bunch of formulas, and the post looks bad from afar, most people will think "Oh, I need to read all that to even understand the question? Pass." and ignore it, or even worse downvote it. It could be the best question on the site from a mathematical point of view, if it's badly presented it will have more chance to be badly received.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks a million for your feedback.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Post as answer?